# Not showing the Modal

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to show a notification modal when i submit a form.but unfortunately the modal is not popping up here is the code

```js
$("#submitmodalRetailer").submit(function() {
  var FirstName = $('#FirstNameRetailer').val();
  var LastName = $('#LastNameRetailer').val();
  var QRCodeRetailer = $('#QRCodeRetailer').val();
  var prefixNumberRetailers = $('#prefixNumberRetailer').val();
  var Retailer7Digits = $('#Retailer7Digit').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addRetailer.php",
    data: $('form.form-modal-retailer').serialize(),
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#RetailerAdd").modal('hide');
      location.reload();
      if (msg == 'Valid') {
        $("#RetailerAddshow").modal('show');
      } else if (msg == 'AlreadyExists') {
        $("#BarcodeExists").modal();
      } else if (msg == 'Invalid') {
        alert('Your Barcode number is invalid. \n User only 100001 to 199999')
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("failure");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: because you have used location.reload(); before the valid notification pop up.. your page will get reload and the further code will not execute

Comment: `location.reload();` will refresh the page and none of the code will get executed after this line.

Answer (score 0):

You may remove

```
location.reload();
```

in Ajax success method to avoid page reload that hinder popup from showing up.

and also you can add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in the button click event to prevent the form submit to cause reloading that may also hinder popup from showing.
and you need to add e as a parameter to event.

```js
$("#submitmodalRetailer").submit(function(e) {.
  e.preventDefault();
  var FirstName = $('#FirstNameRetailer').val();
  var LastName = $('#LastNameRetailer').val();
  var QRCodeRetailer = $('#QRCodeRetailer').val();
  var prefixNumberRetailers = $('#prefixNumberRetailer').val();
  var Retailer7Digits = $('#Retailer7Digit').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addRetailer.php",
    data: $('form.form-modal-retailer').serialize(),
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#RetailerAdd").modal('hide');
      // location.reload();
      if (msg == 'Valid') {
        $("#RetailerAddshow").modal('show');
      } else if (msg == 'AlreadyExists') {
        $("#BarcodeExists").modal();
      } else if (msg == 'Invalid') {
        alert('Your Barcode number is invalid. \n User only 100001 to 199999')
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("failure");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to prevent the default action of the submit button.
Use `preventDefault()`.
Read about it here: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
 $("#submitmodalRetailer").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```